# constructor in class cannot be applied to given types error

Tags: java

I am working on a basic text fighting game project for class. I am trying to get the first option to work before i tackle the second.  My teacher in class won't explain things in detail, he wants the students to figure it out on our own. i just can't figure out how to call the match class.  I have done it this same way in other programs, for some reason it won't work in this one.  I was given the match class by the teacher, and I must make the main class(BattleBots).  this is what i have so far.
thanks in advance.

```
public class BattleBots;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand=new Random();
        Match match1 = new Match();      

        String bot1;
        String bot2;
        int autoOffense1=0;
        int autoDefense1=0;
        int autoOffense2=0;
        int autoDefense2=0; 

    System.out.println("*********************************************************");
    System.out.println("*                    Battle Bots                        *"); 
    System.out.println("*********************************************************");
    int z=0;
    while(z<4)
    {
    System.out.println("1 - Auto generate bot");
    System.out.println("2 - Customize bot");
    System.out.println("3 - Start Match!!!");
    System.out.println("4 - Exit");
    System.out.print("Please choose an option: ");
    z=in.nextInt();

    if (z==1)
    {
       util=new Utilities();      
       System.out.print("Please enter name for bot 1: ");
       bot1=(in.next());
       System.out.print("Please enter name for bot 2: ");
       bot2=(in.next());
       autoOffense1 = (util.roll(10,5,10));
       autoDefense1 = (util.roll(10,5,10));
       autoOffense2 = (util.roll(10,5,10));
       autoDefense2 = (util.roll(10,5,10));

       System.out.println("Bot "+bot1);
       System.out.println("       Offense = "+autoOffense1);
       System.out.println("       Defense = "+autoDefense1);
       System.out.println("Bot "+bot2);
       System.out.println("       Offense = "+autoOffense2);
       System.out.println("       Defense = "+autoDefense2);

    }  
    if (z==2)
    {
     //option2        

    }
    if (z==3)
    {
     match1.startMatch();

     }   
   }


    package battlebots;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Match      //do not modify this class
    {
    private String b1;
    private int b1O;
    private int b1D;
    private int b1HP;
    private String b2;
    private int b2O;
    private int b2D;
    private int b2HP;

    private Utilities util;

    public Match(String bot1, int b1Offense, int b1Defense, int b1HitPoints, String bot2, int b2Offense, int b2Defense, int b2HitPoints)
    {
        util = new Utilities();
        b1=bot1;
        b1O=b1Offense;
        b1D=b1Defense;
        b1HP=b1HitPoints;
        b2=bot2;
        b2O=b2Offense;
        b2D=b2Defense;
        b2HP=b2HitPoints;
    }

    private void attack(int bot)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        if (bot == 1)
        {
            int offense=util.roll(b1O);
            int defense=util.roll(b2D);
            if (offense > defense)
            {
                int damage=rand.nextInt(Math.abs(offense-defense))+1;
                b2HP-=damage;
                System.out.println("\t\t"+b1+"'s attack ("+offense+") suceeded dealing "+damage+" points! "+b2+" failed to defend ("+defense+")!");
                System.out.println("\t\t"+b2+" has "+b2HP+" points left");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("\t\t"+b1+"'s attack ("+offense+") failed! "+b2+" suceeded at defending ("+defense+")!");
        }
        else
        {
            int offense=util.roll(b2O);
            int defense=util.roll(b1D);
            if (offense > defense)
            {
                int damage=rand.nextInt(Math.abs(offense-defense)+1);
                b1HP-=damage;
                System.out.println("\t\t"+b2+"'s attack ("+offense+") suceeded dealing "+damage+" points! "+b1+" failed to defend ("+defense+")!");
                System.out.println("\t\t"+b1+" has "+b1HP+" points left");
            }
            else
                System.out.println("\t\t"+b2+"'s attack ("+offense+") failed! "+b1+" suceeded at defending ("+defense+")!");
        }
    }

    public String startMatch()
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int round=0;
        System.out.println("\n\n * * * * * Start Match!!! * * * * *");
        System.out.println(b1+" O="+b1O+" D="+b1D+" HP="+b1HP);
        System.out.println(b2+" O="+b2O+" D="+b2D+" HP="+b2HP);
        System.out.println("Press 's' to start match!");
        String str=in.next();
        while ((b1HP > 0) && (b2HP > 0))
        {
            round++;
            System.out.println("\nRound "+round);
            if (util.rollInitiative(b1O,b2O) == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("\t"+b1+" got initiative and it is attacking!");
                attack(1);
                attack(2);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("\t"+b2+" got initiative and it is attacking!");
                attack(2);
                attack(1);
            }
        }
        if (b1HP > 0)
            return b1;
        else
            return b2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match takes parameters:

```
public Match(String bot1, int b1Offense, int b1Defense, int b1HitPoints, String bot2, int b2Offense, int b2Defense, int b2HitPoints)
```

Try:

```
Match match1 = new Match("bot1", 5, 5, 10, "bot2", 5, 5, 10);
```